# Implementing international multistore shop workflow

Tags: product, multistore, product-list, localisation

Under a single www.domain.com URL, I have to implement an international shop that does the following:

1) Identify the customer's country (Done)

2) Identify the customer's browser language (Done)

3) Match the browser language with a choice of implemented translations (about 10) and show the front end **and store** in that language. If not supported, fall back to English.

4) Load that customer's country specific listing (we have 180! Most are in dollars) and show it.

Any suggestions accepted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you very much for your reply.

Despite our greatest efforts we did not find much support in the Magento community so we had to implement another e-commerce platform. Community support in there was somewhat more "cooperative" and the software platform is much easier to comprehend and to tweak to support 180 different price listings, therefore we are now selling our products on that platform.

Comment: Well, we had all of 1 programmer available (me), 180 listings (1 per country, sadly every country has different sales agreements and local resellers and thus different prices), have to support 7 languages and upwards to 12 currencies. It's been a rough ride but now it's all up and working. At the moment it's still not fully enabled to all countries as agreements are still being contracted, but 50-ish countries, 5 currencies and 5 languages are indeed up and running. So it's possible, even with just 1 guy, but (sadly) we could not do it with Magento.

Comment: Well, we did not add the functionality to boost sales but because without it we can't do our service at all. I did not mention the software used because I don't want to look like advertising other specific solutions, expecially not in a Magento specific section of Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

What we have done in the past with this sort of request is to create a table where you can store mappings of browser language to store.

Then when you are catching the user hitting the site you compare their browser language with your look-up table, if there is a match then simply redirect the user to the appropriate store.